# Variable always gets rounded to 2 decimal places - Python

Tags: variables, precision, python-2.x, epoch, milliseconds

I am getting a float number from a 2D array and the number is shown as 1406711403.588 in the array when I debugged through it. I get the variable like this

t = array_name[0][0]

and the t became 1406711403.59 no matter what format or round method I used it always like this. I tried it in terminal:

```
>>> t = round(1406711403.588, 3)
>>> print t
1406711403.59
>>> t = round(1406711403.588, 2)
>>> print t
1406711403.59
>>> round(1406711403.588, 3)
1406711403.588
>>>
```

Why it always round it to 2 decimal places ? How can I keep the original precision ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with `print` and not `round`. Try this:

```
>>> round(1406711403.588, 3)
1406711403.5880001
>>> print round(1406711403.588, 3)
1406711403.59
```

`print` will do that rounding automatically unless you specify something else. You can specify the number of decimal points like so:

```
>>> print "%.3f" % (round(1406711403.588, 3))
1406711403.588
>>> print "%.5f" % (round(1406711403.588, 3))
1406711403.58800
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But when i debug until the line of t = array_name[0][0] the value of t shown in the variable list in PyCharm is actually rounded i.e 1406711403.59. I need this variable t to have exactly the same precision as the value in the array. How to achieve this ? Is it just displayed in the variable list view in the debug windows as rounded and it is actually not rounded ??

Comment: @CrazyGreenHand yes that's probably the case. The value itself isn't rounded, that's just how it gets displayed with `print`. You can try printing it out with different precision values (as shown above) to double-check.